# Combining lines in character vector in R

Tags: regex, r, text

I have a character vector (content) of about 50,000 lines in R. However, some of the lines when read in from a text file are on separate lines and should not be. Specifically, the lines look something like this:

```
[1] hello,
[2] world
[3] ""
[4] how
[5] are 
[6] you
[7] ""
```

I would like to combine the lines so that I have something that looks like this:

```
[1] hello, world
[2] how are you
```

I have tried to write a for loop:

```
for(i in 1:length(content)){
    if(content[i+1] != ""){
        content[i+1] <- c(content[i], content[i+1])
    }
}
```

But when I run the loop, I get an error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.

Can anyone suggest a better way to do this, maybe not even using a loop?

Thanks!

EDIT:
I am actually trying to apply this to a Corpus of documents that are all many thousands lines each. Any ideas on how to translate these solutions into a function that can be applied to the content of each of the documents?

Comment: You get the error because `content[i+1]` is missing.

Comment: @Heroka, could you explain a bit more?

Comment: You are iterating over the length of content, and then accessing content at length of content + 1. This generates a missing value. But this approach will not easily yield your desired output, working on an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are more elegant solutions, but this might be usable for you:

```
chars <- c("hello,","world","","how","are","you","")
###identify groups that belong together (id increases each time a "" is found)
ids <- cumsum(chars=="")

#split vector (an filter out "" by using the select vector)
select <- chars!=""
splitted <- split(chars[select], ids[select])

#paste the groups together
res <- sapply(splitted,paste, collapse=" ")

#remove names(if necessary, probably not)
res <- unname(res) #thanks @Roland

> res
[1] "hello, world" "how are you"
```

Comment: I was going to propose this too. You can also use `unname` for the last step.

Comment: @Roland didn't know about that one, thanks. Edited answer.

Comment: Internally it basically does what you were doing. It's just slightly more convenient and more readable.

Comment: @Heroka - I edited the question above, but any idea how to apply this to a Corpus of text files?

Comment: @Heroka used lapply on the corpus I manipulated a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

you don't need a loop to do that

```
x <- c("hello,", "world", "", "how", "\nare", "you", "")

dummy <- paste(
  c("\n", sample(letters, 20, replace = TRUE), "\n"), 
  collapse = ""
) # complex random string as a split marker
x[x == ""] <- dummy #replace empty string by split marker
y <- paste(x, collapse = " ") #make one long string
z <- unlist(strsplit(y, dummy)) #cut the string at the split marker
gsub(" $", "", gsub("^ ", "", z)) # remove space at start and end
```

Comment: Nice one. Tiny thing: your solution generates sentences with a space at the start. And is this scalable to 50000 lines?

Comment: Can we be sure that non of the strings contains `\n`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach using `data.table` which is likely to be faster than `for` or `*apply` loops:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x)
dt[, .(paste(x, collapse = " ")), rleid(x == "")][V1 != ""]$V1
#[1] "hello, world" "how are you"
```

Sample data:

```
x <- c("hello,", "world", "", "how", "are", "you", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `""` with something you can later split on, and then collapse the characters together, and then use `strsplit()`.  Here I have used the newline character since if you were to just paste it you could get the different lines on the output, e.g. `cat(txt3)` will output each phrase on a separate line.

```
txt <-  c("hello", "world", "", "how", "are", "you", "", "more", "text", "")
txt2 <- gsub("^$", "\n", txt)
txt3 <- paste(txt2, collapse = " ")
unlist(strsplit(txt3, "\\s\n\\s*"))
## [1] "hello world" "how are you" "more text"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to add to the mix:

```
tapply(x[x != ''], cumsum(x == '')[x != '']+1, paste, collapse=' ')
#             1              2              3 
#"hello, world"  "how are you"    "more text"
```

Group by non-empty strings. And paste the elements together by group.